# Make Django REST framework and Django Channels play nicely

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I want to make the Django REST Framework work with web sockets and came across Django Channels. Can I build Channels on top of the REST Framework?

I read [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/mozilla-grant/#realtime-apis) that it is WIP, however I was wondering if there is an easy 'light' way to tie the two together. Any advice is appreciated, I'm still rather new to Django.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do,If you are looking for creating API's endpoint in realtime , right now its not possible.

Incase serializing messages on top of Django ,there is a project https://github.com/linuxlewis/channels-api .

Comment: Provides a good example - it is unfortunate that there is no build in permission functionality yet.

Answer (score 8):

Roy van der Valk - have you had any luck so far?

I've had success launching our platform which uses traditional Django views, Django-Rest-Framework views and channels 'consumers'.

There is a guncorn/wsgi substitute called Daphne - it will mitigate the request itself (wherever http/websocket etc..) to it's correct response handler. It uses a separate request handler called - asgi.

The trick was in crafting the django application level urls to dispatch the 'http.request' channel to the correct urls configuration which handled our traditional Django and Django-Rest-Framework views.

The rest of the asgi channels had 'views' or channels created to handle them appropriately.

Let me know if this is enough to get you moving in the right direction. I can provide you with links/details if you provide me with specific problems.

Comment: Thanks @Richael - I had put it aside for a moment, but this sparks my interest to pick it up again!

Comment: @Richael. I would like to know. What have you done? I need to launch a chat that comunicates trough api.
with rest-framework and plain django. but the two projects are on separates instances. What is the aproach that I need to? Include Channels on the web django or include it on the api?

Answer (score 2):

There is a package called `DCRF (djangochannelsrestframework)` provides a DRF like interface for building `channels-v3` websocket consumers.

https://github.com/NilCoalescing/djangochannelsrestframework

Based on its documentation:

> DCRF is based of a fork of [Channels Api](https://github.com/linuxlewis/channels-api) and of course inspired by [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org).

Hope it can help you.